# Mysql: Syntax error when inserting multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-8.0

I'm inserting 23,000 rows into the database (MySQL 8.0.32, InnoDB engine). If I split the rows into chunks of 15,135 everything works. But If I split it into chunks of 15,136 (the same code), application throws following error:

```
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':ticker_id_0
```

Generated sql is:

```sql
INSERT INTO ticker_time_series (ticker_id,date,close,percentage_change) VALUES (:ticker_id_0,:date_0,:close_0,:percentage_change_0),(:ticker_id_1,:date_1,:close_1,:percentage_change_1),(:ticker_id_2,:date_2,:close_2,:percentage_change_2), ...
```

I tried to increase max_allowed_packet, max_prepared_stmt_count. None of them work.

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't try to use chunks greater than 1,000 regardless. Why are you trying to push the bounds?

Comment: Have you tried insert them all in one go? I regularly recreate a table that contains a little over 150,000 records with no problems at all

Comment: @BillKarwin Why not more than 1,000? Inserting 30-100 x 1,000 is slower than inserting 30,000 at once.

Comment: @JuanCarlos Yes. I split it into chunks because of the syntax error. The same problem with the other tables.

Comment: Your generated SQL query appears to be hitting some length limit, in the prepare phase already. Can you check the DBMS error log, to see if there is any more info in there?

Comment: Inserting chunks of 1,000 rows is already orders of magnitude faster than inserting one row at a time. But inserting 2 chunks isn't orders of magnitude faster than inserting 30 chunks. And given that you need to loop over chunks anyway, why not use the chunk size that works instead of a chunk size that doesn't work?

Comment: Also, I comment that if bulk insert performance is so important, you shouldn't be using INSERT at all. You should use LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: I am not sure what limit you are hitting at `15,136`, but there is a hard limit of `65,535` (UINT_MAX16) for the maximum number of placeholders. This would limit you to `16,383` rows per multi-insert anyway.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you for your comments. You're right and yes, I am using a lower number of chunks, but I was trying to understand where the problem is.

Comment: @CBroe unfortunately I didn't find anything

Comment: @Martin  What is result of SELECT @@group_concat_max_len;  ?

Comment: @WilsonHauck 1024

Comment: I don't know what is causing the error either, but you haven't shown your code, so I'm making some assumptions in my head about how you have implemented the code. One possibility is that this is a problem in PDO, not MySQL. PDO is responsible for transforming named placeholders like `:ticker_id_0` into the placeholders that MySQL understands, which is only a positional style placeholder `?`. Maybe PDO only does that transformation for the first N characters? I don't know.

Comment: @Martin  Please consider just after error message is diaplayed, FLUSH LOGS; and then post last 30 lines of your error log from MySQL error log for analysis.

Comment: @Martin   Could you post the last 80 characters of the generated sql:  Thanks,

Comment: @BillKarwin Looks like there's a problem with the pdo. Inserting sql without placeholders in phpmyadmin is successful

Comment: I can confirm that the problem is elsewhere than in the database. It's in the library I'm using. Thanks to everyone for their comments